# Configure RHEL service so that it recognizes Amazon IP address of host EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel

Versions

```
OS: RHEL 8.x
```

I've installed a service -- call it `foosvc` -- to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/foo.service`, with configuration something like this:

```
[Unit]
...
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
...
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/foosvc fg
...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the host EC2 reboots, this service restarts as expected.  However, there seems to be a race condition:  namely, if I restart the service manually,

```
sudo systemctl restart foosvc
```

it listens on port 6000 as follows:

```
foosvc   780 username   21u  IPv4  22462      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6000 (LISTEN)
foosvc   780 username   21u  IPv4  22462      0t0  TCP 172.30.41.149:6000 (LISTEN)
```

where IP address `172.30.41.149` is the IP internal to AWS, and the external IP is the elastic IP (not listed here) attached to this EC2.

However, if I reboot the EC2 from the dashboard, `foosvc` auto-starts as expected, but is listening to port 6000 only for the loopback IP address:

```
foosvc   780 username   21u  IPv4  22462      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6000 (LISTEN)
```

QUESTION:  how can `foosvc` be configured so that on system reboots, `foosvc` listens to port 6000 on both localhost and the internal AWS IP address?

NOTE:  `foosvc` listens for both TCP and UDP on port 6000.

Answer (score 0):

Private IP address is allocated via DHCP. You need the interface to become routable before starting your service.

1. Create a [configuration file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.network.html) for your main ENI in `/etc/systemd/network`, and specify `RequiredForOnline=routable`.
2. In your service configuration file, create a requirement dependency on [`systemd-networkd-wait-online`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html). Make sure it's enabled.